# HomePlug units on different ring circuits?

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

Can I connect two [HomePlug](https://www.homeplug.org/home/) units to two different [ring circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_circuit) in the same house, and expect them to be able to talk to one another?

Both circuits terminate at the same [consumer unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_unit).

Comment: The key thing with powerline is phase. As long as they are on the same phase, they should be able to communicate. This might also be of interest to you in designing a powerline network: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_line_communication#Failure_Scenarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never tell 100% for sure, but I expect it to work. Networks "withing" a consumer unit usually work without flaws. Often the plugs can even communicate through consumer units, it is even told (unencrypted) networks between houses got linked.

Answer (score 1):

I find that when transmitting other frequencies over the AC wires anywhere, that we had more problems from "Filters" than from the interconnection of the AC circuitry.  UPS devices, Surge protectors, power conditioning boxes and even other devices with "filter" items on the AC side.

In most homes the idea works great, and worked great in this one too, then as we started adding in "gear" of all sorts, we slowly lost this type of communications for our purposes completly. EX: We could directally attribute the loss of communications to something as simple and cheap as a 6-pax power strip with built in "surge protection". we kept trying to shift things around, and get closer on wire communications, until it was no longer feasable for all the "Stuff" I have connected.

Comment: (+1) Just to be clear, do you find that filters interfere when they're placed *between* the HomePlug units, or even when they're simply connected to an unrelated place in the AC circuitry?

Comment: The second one,  on that "curcuit" anywhere. I could use a different curcuit. Curcuit meaning house wiring connection from the power box to the wall socket.  We had communications from completly different AC curcuits working fine. then put a filter ON the curcuit, and it would fail, or work poorly.