# How Can I Connect Two Sets of Computers Within My Home Office So There's No Cables On the Floor?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, cabling

I have a group of five computers at one end of my home office and another group of four computers across the same room. All are hardwired on the same internal network. These cannot be consolidate or moved into one corner or closet. There just is not the space and it's just physically not possible.

There is one Internet router as provided by the local cable company. I have this connected to a **LinkSys WRT54G2** broadband router. A **Netgear DS108** 8-port hub is connected the LinkSys. All computers either connect to the Netgear hub or to the LinkSys router. As of now, the WiFi from the LinkSys router is only ever used by my cell phone while at home.

This set up is annoying. At first I did not mind, but there are cables on the floor that I have to step over. These CAT5 cables connect one set of computers to the LinkSys or Netgear. I have to watch where visitors are walking or stepping to assure they don't trip.

How can I keep these computers on the same network and eliminate just those cables crossing the floor of my home office?

It seems easy to see my only option is to use some kind of wireless method, right?

Should I use WiFi NICs? Would this overwhelm the WiFi on the LinkSys?

*(Although I did first search this site for similar questions, I could not readily find one. If you find one I missed, please share it's link.)*

Thank you for any help.

**Additional (01/27/2012 at 16:40:28 UTC)**

This is a rented flat/apartment. I cannot pull up carpet, punch holes in walls, and there's no access to attic. Modifying the flat risks losing my 'security deposit'.

Comment: that's a good idea!!! you can use pci WiFi nic's their configuration & installation is very simple.

Comment: But at what point does the WiFi LinkSys router get overwhelmed? Three WiFi NICs? Six WiFi NICS? Or never? I was looking at USB WiFi NICs. I guess it's better to use PIC, huh?

Comment: The wifi AP's bandwidth is shared between all connected nodes - they'd be sharing the 54 Mb/s of bandwidth between all of them.

Comment: It's all depends on you & No of IP's you allowed in dhcp server of your router also, you can limit your no of connections, if you want to  increase your wifi range you can use cheap repeater or wifi range extender (Linksys RE1000) http://helpspa.com/networking_internet/limit-the-number-of-connections-to-a-linksys-wireless-router/

Comment: *"How can I keep these computers on the same network and eliminate just those cables crossing the floor of my home office?"* - the easiest solution to that would be to sticky tape them to the ceiling surely

Comment: one missing information: how much information flows through the network ???? the computers are heavily used, or just exchange small amounts of information between them? or all just access the internet ?

Comment: @woliveirajr Good observation and thank you for asking. I mentioned that this is my home office. Yes, my business depends upon these computers. I push and pull data over the Internet. Two machines are Windows servers with SQL Server running. I am a software developer and my programs use the SQL servers. I would assume the traffic over the private network is substantial.

Comment: Suspend the cables with a series of poles, then they will not be on the floor.

Comment: Data transfer requirements are not stated. Anyway, get a switch for the 5 to plug into, then connect that to the router.  The other four can either be wired to another switch and a bridge or just use WiFi NICs.  Try and group your PCs that need to have the fastest file transfer rates on the same wired segment using the bridge & router for internet access mainly.

Comment: FYI...have the same WiFi and three PCs connected.  With all 3 streaming video from YouTube we have no problems.

Comment: Wireless N is fine. I have wireless N on my laptop and it's fast enough to stream 1080p. It shouldn't be a problem. When transferring a file to my NAS over wireless, I get 20Mb/s or more. Should be fast enough for your needs.

Comment: Staple the cables to the ceiling.

Answer (score 16):

I would use [powerline networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_line_communication#Home_networking_.28LAN.29) to link to a switch at the far end.

You can buy a pair of [HomePlug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug_Powerline_Alliance) units that plug into ordinary wall electric sockets. They will bridge the two ends of the room together without any cables lying on the floor.

[image: Diagram of Homeplug network]
[image: A combined homeplug adapater & ethernet switch]

Comment: I second this idea, Powerline is a lot faster in general than wifi and doesn't suffer from so many problems as wifi can, especially if your going to be streaming video over the connection.

Comment: -1 For all the difficulties I have seen using powerline networking in general.

Comment: I am hesitant about this idea. But, let me ask this. I know from experience, that one side of the room is on one circuit and the other side on a separate circuit. Does this work across separate electrical circuits?

Comment: @Steve: According to the [FAQ](https://www.homeplug.org/about/faqs/) that should be OK even if they are on different phases. Normally all the circuits in one room are wired to a common fusebox (AKA consumer unit) or point of supply into the building.

Comment: @Steve: See also http://superuser.com/q/348692/52492  and http://www.jdhunt.com/homeplug/aug07/PLC_Cross-phase_Coupling.pdf

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Thanks for the info. I just found this article **"Install Powerline Network Adapters without Neighbor Interference"** [link](http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/how-to/4213418) The article mentions some points about security. My business relies upon these 10+/- computers having a reliable network connection and strong security.

Comment: Powerline networking seems overkill for this...

Comment: This DOES sound like a BIG security risk! After all, it IS publicly accessible infrastructure.

Comment: Powerline is a poor choice.  There's a reason it hasn't been adopted widely.

Comment: @Steve: as that link says "all powerline networking gear either requires pairing via physical buttons on each device, or includes an optional encryption scheme, similar to that used with Wi-Fi, that will prevent anyone from jumping on your network -- even if you're on the same circuit." A typical product spec says "128-bit AES Link Encryption with key management for secure powerline communications"

Comment: Yes, and that's what I understood from the article. Call me paranoid, but I am just not comfortable with this option. As @ChefFlambe pointed out, it is not widely adopted. I feel WiFi has had a lot more experience. Either way, this option seems like I am handing my CAT5 cable to my neighbors here in the building. Just saying.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarrified my objection.  Security wise it's about the same as WiFi.  My experience is through-put at distance is inconsistant at best. AC lines are giant antenna so if you're near a RF site then you'll get heaps of noise on your AC plus all the noise from other in building items, and that slows things down.  The claims for 100-1000Mbps are done on super clean 60Hz circuits, so what you get will vary alot.  I had a commercial grade system running for tests in a buisness environment and the max distance I could get it to work was 30 feet at a dodgy 10Mbps. We went WiFi.

Answer (score 9):

Buy a couple of cheap switches, put them on either side of the room and plug in the PCs on that side.  Run *one* cable neatly around the perimeter of the room, plug one end into your router and the other into the switch on the far side of the room.  Connect the other switch that's on the same side as the router.

Comment: I had looked into your idea initially but realized the pattern of foot traffic would mean one wire would remain a tripping hazard.

Comment: Even if you run the cable along the ceiling? You don't *have* to string the cable along the floor just because it's a cable.

Comment: There is also flat Ethernet cable that when taped down presents a lot smaller 'bump' to foot traffic either on the floor or under carpet/rugs.

Comment: The cable can also run along the base of a wall.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Again, I cannot run a cable around the perimeter of the room.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Not a very attractive option, huh.

Comment: The point here, Steve, is that one cable can be easily taped down so as not to trip over it. If you run it along _anything_, it will be even less of an already negligible trip hazard. After all, it's only an 8th of an inch high (or half a centimeter) and can't be picked up on top of a foot.

Comment: I am fully aware of the options to tape down, staple up, or just run a cable along the perimeter of the room. It is more than just aesthetics that prevent me from doing these.

Comment: *AESTHETICALLY* you'd get a network cabling company in to install wall sockets, cabinets and probably a small 6U patch cabinet for it all - No bottlenecks, no 'trippable' cables, full security and a professional setup. None of this stop-gap and 'fixing cables with tape' solutions. **But you've said you're not prepared/able to do this the professional way.**

Comment: Sidenote: ask your landlord what solution they would prefer. You might find them very accomodating when you suggest getting a network cabling company in to do it professionally. It adds value to their building...

Answer (score 3):

Get a pair of wireless access points that support Wireless Distribution System (WDS), use them to bridge the two locations on your network sans-wire.

There are pre-configured WLAN bridges that do all the work for you, like e.g. the Zyxel WAP5605. You attach them to a hub or router on either end of your setup.

Comment: Thanks Zoredache. Doing some research on your idea. To be clear that I understand, with existing routers & hub, I could add two new WAPs and config those as a bridge? Yes? No? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you'll need another router for this, but this sounds pretty much like what [dd-wrt client mode](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless) is designed to handle. You'll need a wireless router that supports the firmware, and you can connect the PCs on one side of the room to the ethernet ports on the router running in client mode (so you only need one device, and you can use conventional ethernet to connect those systems, rather than have multiple wireless adaptors), have the AP and other computers on the other side.

Comment: Thanks Journeyman Geek, I'll research your idea further.

Comment: I use DD-WRT for this purpose with great success in my home office.

Answer (score 3):

You could leave the cables running along the floor and use a [cable protector](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=sr_nr_n_2?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A79903031%2Cn%3A1938265031%2Ck%3Acable+protector&keywords=cable+protector&ie=UTF8&qid=1490049433&rnid=79904031) to protect them and prevent tripping.

[image: cable protector]

Comment: mixed feelings on this. Depending on the location & flooring you can end up with the carpet being protected from the sun and a line being left when you remove it.

Comment: If there is carpet, even better. Pull it back, cables go under.

Comment: Yes, its a carpeted rented flat. I would lose my security deposit if I pulled up the carpeting, even just a little. And these 'Cable Protection' do not keep people from tripping, they only protect cables.

Answer (score 3):

There's another option if you have coax (cable TV) outlets in both locations;  you can use MoCA adapters.  MoCA sends Ethernet over coax without interfering with cable TV signals. I use this in my house to communicate between the first and third floors.   Speed is comparable to a  wired 100Mb connection (a little faster than powerline Ethernet, which I also use.)

Verizon FIOS routers implement MoCA, and used ones can usually be found on eBay for less than $50.  They also include a 4-port switch.  You would need one for both ends of your connection.

More info here:

http://www.avsforum.com/avs-vb/showthread.php?t=1145636

Comment: Interesting option. However, for me, there's only one coax (cable TV) outlet.

Comment: Oops, just made a duplicate answer. Oh well. Note that you can get a pair of receivers for only $80 http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001N85NMI

Comment: This is also a good read: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jimc/documents/net-moca-1101.html

Answer (score 1):

#### Multimedia over Coax Alliance

As an alternative to power line networking, you can use MoCA. It allows you to do networking communication across your already existing coaxial cable.

Powerline networking has improved over the years, but it's not perfect. Newer implementations can also be expensive. MoCA doesn't use noisy powerlines that were never at all designed for such a thing.

Honestly, I don't think either solution is really a good idea for ***just across the room***, but I thought I would mention it, since I think it's a better solution than powerline networking.

The equipment is only ~$80 for a pair and boasts 270mb connectivity. (Just like powerline networking, that's a theoretical max, but you should see 70mb in most situations)
[http://www.amazon.com/NETGEAR-MCAB1001-Coax-Ethernet-Adapter-Black/dp/B001N85NMI/?t=slickdeals&tag=slickdeals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001N85NMI)

Answer (score 0):

If its your house, stick the cables into the wall cavity.

Comment: I wish I could, but the place is a rented flat.

Answer (score 0):

3M Command Strips are the security deposit's best friend. Specifically, 3M makes a "[Medium Chord Clip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000AQOHL)" which will hold your cables more snugly than pounding something into your wall, and will come off completely clean when you move out.

They're a little bit pricey, but less so than an additional router, and they won't require you to change your network setup at all.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like a "backdrop support" ( [Photo from shop I don't work for etc. etc](http://www.borrowlenses.com/images/store/photoflex__Custom_.jpg)). Can be obtained from a photo supply store, and fairly inexpensive. Put one in each corner of room, raise it to ceiling height, and run the cables across it with tie-wraps. Adjustable, portable.